# python library to retrieve device information from android mobile phone by making an app Using Python only

Tags: python, android, mdm

I am looking for a library that can be used to retrieve device information from android device by making an app to run on android devce just to send data to a sql server Using Only Python

I have searched everywhere for the library and making an app using python only but didn't get any information about it.

Comment: What kind of data? And you not find any networking library to post data to your backend?

Comment: Use the Linux API. There are many virtual files inside /proc and /dev which give you device informations.